# ¿Cómo Detectar si un DialogFragment se encuentra visible en Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

¿Cómo se puede detectar si un DialogFragment está visible? para evitar a instanciar uno de nuevo.

```
AppRateDialog myDiag = new AppRateDialog();
myDiag.show(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), "AppRateDialog");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basado en este hilo de [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352571/android-how-do-i-check-if-dialogfragment-is-showing)

**Forma normal:** Para detectar un fragmento:

```
Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag");

if(prev == null)
    //Aqúi si no está activo el fragment
else
    //Se está mostrandose o en la pila
```

**Usando support-v4:** 
Si los `DialogFragment` son creados con la librería de soporte de Google (support-v4) para Material design, se debe usar `getSupportFragmentManager()`

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
...
Fragment prev = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag");

if(prev == null) {
    //Aqúi si no está activo el fragment    }
else {
    //Se está mostrandose o en la pila
}
```

**Código de prueba:**

```
Fragment prev = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("AppRateDialog");
if(prev == null) {
    AppRateDialog myDiag = new AppRateDialog();
    myDiag.show(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), "AppRateDialog");
} else {
    Log.w(TAG, "Prevent creat AppRateDialog: ");
}
```

Comment: Como lo mencionas es correcto, solo detectando si la instancia del fragmento tiene valor null o no. si es null no esta visible.